# Autosyncing SQL database to AWS RDS

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've got a SQL database somewhere outside AWS. I would like my AWS RDS instance to poll this server every couple of hours and incrementally sync, i.e. load only stuff that is not already on the RDS instance. How would I go about this **in the most efficient way**?